# RootFS types, creation and booting

Tags: linux, u-boot, rootfs

If you are developing anything on embedded Linux you need a Rootfs to boot Linux.   Rootfs has always been a issue for me. I need some help.
My target system is ARM, U-Boot Linux simple.

a) I have seen a **rootfs.tar.gz** file which is copied from SD card to say `0x60000000` and then a

```
bootm 0x40000000 0x50000000 0x60000000
```

-Does U-Boot uncompresses the rootfs image?
-How does Linux know which type of rootfs it is?

b) If bootarg is passed as `root=/dev/mmcblk1p1`, how does Linux know which type of rootfs it is?

c) `sudo qemu-debootstrap --arch=armel precise ./precise/` creates directories with bin and other entries.  How do I create a **tar.gz** out of it?

Comment: like i said i dont know much abt it, kindly describe the diff

Comment: ok, then (b) in my q is rootfs and (a) is initramfs

Comment: **Correction:** that `bootm` command specifies a **ramdisk image**. An **initramfs** would use a `cpio` archive, not a `tar` archive.  My bad.  The reference documentation is [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt).  Where did you read the instructions or example you mention in "question a"?

Comment: Did I make an incorrect edit to your question?  Are you developing for an ARM target on a PC host? Or are you actually developing natively **on** an ARM host?

Answer (score 0):

In bootm you are specifying the system to where it can take the image of kernel.
Regarding filesystem, your filesystem reside in root=/dev/mmcblk1p1. 
So copy the rootfs.tar.gz file in mmc and extract that .gz in mmc.